# XNA spawning multiple enemies

Tags: c#, xna

Ok, I'm sure that i am just missing something really easy because i just can't find the answer ANYWHERE. I am making an infinite runner game(2d), but i can get one enemy spawning right at the start, and that's it. What the heck am i missing? Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame1
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    static Random enemyspawner = new Random();
    int enemyloc = enemyspawner.Next(500) + 500;
    /*GraphicsDeviceManager, SpriteBatch, Texture2D and Vector2 may be found only in XNA. They are just used for drawing objects and defining locations.*/
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphic;
    SpriteBatch SpriteBatch;
    Texture2D charr;
    int enemyspeed = 1;
    Vector2 charPos;
    bool jumping; //Is the character jumping?
    float startY, jumpspeed = 0; //startY to tell us //where it lands, jumpspeed to see how fast it jumps
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D grass;
    Texture2D enemy;
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {


        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        charr = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"dog_jump"); //Load image
        charPos = new Vector2(230, 415);//Char loc, X/Y
        grass = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"grass1");
        enemy = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"fire hydrant");
        startY = charPos.Y;//Starting position
        jumping = false;//Init jumping to false
        jumpspeed = 0;//Default no speed

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x == 1000; x++ )
        {
            enemyspeed++;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x == 75; x++)
        {
            x = 0;
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(enemy, new Vector2(enemyloc, 450), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            enemyloc = enemyspawner.Next(500);

        }
        enemyloc -= enemyspeed;
        //Init keyboard
KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
if (jumping)
{
charPos.Y += jumpspeed;//Making it go up
jumpspeed += 1;//Some math (explained later)
    if (charPos.Y >= startY)
    //If it's farther than ground
    {
        charPos.Y = startY;//Then set it on
           jumping = false;
    }
}
else
{
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) 
{
    jumping = true;
    jumpspeed = -12;//Give it upward thrust
}
}

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(grass, new Vector2(0, 450), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(charr, charPos, Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();
        Spawner();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
    public void Spawner()
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(enemy, new Vector2(enemyloc, 450 - 50),      Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
}
```

Also, yes i did get te gravity code off the internet, nothing that i tried was working

Comment: You want multiple enemys on the screen? You only have one instance of your enemy, you need to create multiple instances of the enemy.

Comment: How would i do that @Vajura ?

Comment: I don't mean to speak for Vajura but you could have an array or list of type enemy (which will be a class you have to write). It all depends on what you want. It looks like your code is meant to just keep re-drawing the enemy at a new position every time which if you are only wanting one obstacle is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the second for loop in the update method you are setting x to zero every time. That will prevent it from getting outside of that loop and that would explain the behaviour you have seen

Answer (score 0):

first of all, this doesn't make any sense:

```
    for (int x = 0; x == 1000; x++ )
    {
        enemyspeed++;
    }
```

This only increases the speed if x equals 1000.
You will get the same result if you remove the for loop, but you probably want this: `for (int x = 0; x <1000; x++ )//increases speed 1000 times`

You also got a problem here:

```
    for (int x = 0; x == 75; x++)//same here as mentioned above
    {
        x = 0;
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(enemy, new Vector2(enemyloc, 450), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        enemyloc = enemyspawner.Next(500);
    }
```

Also, you keep setting x to 0, so this loop will run forever.

EDIT:

```
for (int x = 0; x == 1000; x++ )
```

I looked at it again and I coudn't find any reason why you would increase the speed 1000 times, by using a for loop. So I believe/assume you want to update the speed after 1000 updates? In that case, this is what you want:

```
//Add a atrubit count to your class:
int count = 0;

//Update method:
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    count++;//update count

    if(count % 1000 == 0){
        enemyspeed++;//update speed after 1000 updates
    }
    if(count % 75 == 0){//draw after 75 updates
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(enemy, new Vector2(enemyloc, 450), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        enemyloc = enemyspawner.Next(500);
    }

    //do your other stuff

}
```

Comment: I can see your logic but i did want the loop to be infinite. Every time x reaches 75 it draws an enemy. I don't want to draw just one enemy, so i set x back to 0 to start the for loop again. Also i tried to implement the code but it didn't work, in fact it made no sprite appear on the screen.

Comment: You never ever want an infinite loop! Your loop won't end now and noting else but the loop is exexuted. Use my loop te create 75 enemies. Also, this sould not be done in your `update`, but in your constuctor. Your update gets executed 60 times in a second.

Comment: oohh i thought that it did that loop seperate from everything else. This is probably my problem, thanks!